# $_SESSION is resettet after refresh

Tags: php, html, forms, session-variables

i have a question.

I'm try to get store a $_GET Value in a $_SESSION value.

my form:

```
 <form name="get_categorie" class="form-group" action="[{$oViewConf->getSslSelfLink()}]cl=subtel_meta_tagger&tpl=promo" method="get">
                    <input type="hidden" name="cl" value="subtel_meta_tagger">
                    <input type="hidden" name="tpl" value="promo">
                    <select class="form-control" id="TLD_opt" name="TLD_opt" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                        <optgroup id="formGroupExampleInput" label="AT - Austria">
                            <option id="formGroupExampleInput" name="add_oxlang_promo" value="AT;1">AT - English</option>
                            <option id="formGroupExampleInput" name="add_oxlang_promo" value="AT;0">AT -German</option>
                        </optgroup>
                        <optgroup id="formGroupExampleInput" label="Belgium - BE" >
                            <option id="formGroupExampleInput" name="add_oxlang_promo" value="BE;1">BE - English</option>
                            <option id="formGroupExampleInput" name="add_oxlang_promo" value="BE;2">BE- France</option>
                            <option id="formGroupExampleInput" name="add_oxlang_promo" value="BE;3">BE- Netherlands</option>
                        </optgroup>
....
</form
```

i save the the Value in a $_SESSION like this

```
public function getCountryAndLang()
    {
        $_SESSION['super_TLD'] = $_GET['TLD_opt'];
        $add_tld = $_SESSION['super_TLD'];
        $res = explode(";", $add_tld);
        $add_tld_promo = $res[0];
        var_dump($add_tld_promo);
        $add_oxlang_promo = $res[1];
        var_dump($add_oxlang_promo);
    }
}
```

i can save it but when i want to insert this values in an other form and get it from the $_SESSION['super_TLD'}

the Value is NULL and i cant post my other form . it means the $_SESSION Value is resettet.

My question is, can i save and use a $_GET value in a $_SESSION or is it the wrong way ?

Comment: Do you have `session_start();` in the beginning of your code? That's required if you want the data you store in the session to be persistent between requests.

Comment: `method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data"` makes rather little sense btw. That enctype is for file uploads, which you are not doing here, and even if you were, those would not happen via GET.

Comment: yes it is in the code,  i forgot to explain it more, i'm working withe the OXID eShop

Comment: @CBroe thanks , i forgot to remove it, i used this in another form.